# werkzeug + django + gunicorn: TypeError

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, werkzeug

I'm new to werkzeug and I'm getting a "TypeError: **init**() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)" when I try to visit a test page after installation and setup. Werkzeug does provide a traceback (see below). I've looked at that and my settings without success.

I've installed the following packages:

```
django_extensions
werkzeug
```

added the following to my Django settings file:

```
########## WERKZEUG/DJANGO EXTENSIONS
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'django_extensions',
    'werkzeug',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
    'werkzeug.debug.DebuggedApplication',
)
########## END WERKZEUG/DJANGO EXTENSIONS
```

and created a dev_wsgi.py file that I call from my gunicorn driver script:

```
# basic wsgi.py
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my-site.settings.dev')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Werkzeug-specific
import django.views.debug

def null_technical_500_response(request, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
    raise exc_type, exc_value, tb
django.views.debug.technical_500_response = null_technical_500_response

# apply Werkzeug WSGI middleware
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
application = DebuggedApplication(application, evalex=True)
```

But now when I view a test URL, I get the following traceback:

```
File "/python2-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
self.load_middleware()
File "/python2-venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 49, in load_middleware
mw_instance = mw_class()
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Commenting out the Werkzeug-specific lines in dev_wsgi.py allows my test page to display correctly. I'm using Werkzeug 0.9.4, django_extensions 1.3.3, django 1.6.4 and Python 2.7.6.

Comment: I also tried disabling Django Debug Toolbar and running both locally (as localhost) and through DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`werkzeug.debug.DebuggedApplication` is a WSGI middleware not a Django middleware. Django middleware expect no arguments to the `__init__` and are added to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. WSGI middleware take at least one argument to the `__init__` which is the WSGI application to be wrapped. You are attempting to use it as both but the fix is simple. Remove `werkzeug.debug.DebuggedApplication` from the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

Comment: Thanks again. I wrote some documentation for a pull request.